# PHP + Smarty: Parse PHP+HTML into a String?

Tags: php, html, smarty, server-side

I am using PHP in combination with Smarty Templates to generate pages serverside. Currently, I am loading a page as follows:

```
$smarty->assign('app', file_get_contents("some_content.php"));
```

Where some content contains HTML with PHP tags and code inside those tags.

I would like the PHP content inside this file within the current scope (That of the script reading the file), so that a particular function I've defined is available. How would I go about doing so? All the information I can find is regarding the eval(...) function, which doesn't seem to be able to cope with the HTML/PHP mixture: would I need to perform a find/eval/replace operation to achieve the desired result, or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my opinion, this short snippet of the code you posted shows that something is generally wrong there :)

But nevertheless you can achieve whatever you are trying to achieve by doing the following:

```
ob_start();
include("some_content.php");
$result = ob_get_clean();
$smarty->assign('app', $result);
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I took your code and made it into a nice little function called parse_in_scope, with the argument being the file to parse and the return value being $result. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: PS, what do you think is 'generally wrong' with the snippet? The code is a bit of an encapsulation of a larger problem, but I'd like to hear what you're thinking :^).

Comment: For me, the only situation that somehow justifies trying to assign evaluated php/html code to Smarty variable is an attempt to use some 3-rd party code "as-is" :)

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing, I actually got a bit sidetracked and it may be unnecessary to do so, but it's nice to have this trick in my tool belt.

Answer (score 1):

Ich, I'm such a dummkopf. There is an answer right on the PHP manual for eval, right under my nose. [Here is the answer I neglected to notice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#108091).

Answer (score 0):

You can use {literal}...{/literal} smarty tags to display any content in smarty templates as is. It used to transfer java scripts and other specific content.